# iOS/FBSDK - FBSDKProfile is nil on device, works fine on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift, fbsdk

As per the title, I am getting nil Optional unwrapping errors when testing on my device, but not the simulator - and I have found the cause of this to be calls to `FBSDKProfile.currentProfile.name` or similar. I remember this causing me pain while developing in the simulator, and I fixed it by adding `FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)` when the user logs in, and if they are already logged in, when the app loads.

Anyone have experience with this issue or have any ideas for a solution? Happy to post code if anyone thinks it would help.

Thanks!

Comment: does ur simulator have fcebook account ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem was that FBSDKProfile takes a few seconds to load and I wasn't giving it the time, and therefore trying to use a nil value.

So the solution was to have placeholder values, and listen for the FBSDK Notification `FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification`, updating those values when it was done.

Here's the code:

In the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("onFBProfileUpdated:"), name: FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

And a separate method:

```
func onFBProfileUpdated(notification: NSNotification) {
    nameLabel.text = FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().name

    setImage(FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().imageURLForPictureMode(FBSDKProfilePictureMode.Square, size: image.frame.size))
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles across the same issue as me.